# Pass URLs as parameters in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is kind of strange.

I have a route:

```
match "program/:program_id" => "program#details"
```

When calling this, everything works:

```
/program/1
```

However, the program IDs I use aren't digits only. They're in fact URLs like so: `crid://blah.com/d1e5`

**How can I pass an URL via a RESTful approach as a paramter?**

Calling this doesn't work, obviously:

```
/program/crid://blah.com/d1e5
/program/crid%3A%2F%2Fblah.com%2Fd1e5
```

Comment: @edgerunner Why did you remove the tags?

Comment: @slhck, that's explained with a somewhat long rant about why tags shouldn't be used as keywords here but rather as platform or expertise identifiers. You get rails experts to see your question, but you don't have anyone who call themselves "parameter passing experts". Such tags only cause pollution in the tagspace. That's why I remove them wherever I see them :) (And your Rails 3 tag is gone because your question isn't version specific)

Comment: @edgerunner I see your point but where is the common consensus on that? (A meta post, a FAQ entry...) Why should there be a tag named "parameter passing" or "REST" after all then?

Comment: @slhck There was a discussion about it on meta. I'll try to dig it up for you. There are all kinds of tags in there, most of them have very little following. The tags that have a proper following are mostly either platform/product tags like Rails or Textmate, or major, platform independent topics like usability (REST would qualify here but your question is about putting a URL into a URL, REST is more about how a resource is represented and accessed, that's why I chopped it.)

Comment: Parameter passing is however is a language specific subtopic that wouldn't make sense to follow. I could easily answer any question about parameter passing in Ruby but I'd totally be lost at parameter passing for C++. A good heuristic for picking useful tags would be thinking if you could see the said tag in a job listing. (Parameter passer with 5+ years experience anyone?) Another good reference is the number of followers a tag has. Keywordish tags have very few followers. Even the most obscure platform/product tag has much more following.

Comment: @edgerunner Thanks for the explanation - I'll consider it the next time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `program/*program_id` instead of `program/:program_id`.

Answer (score 4):

RFC 1738 says:

> ... only alphanumerics, the special characters "$-_.+!*'(),", and reserved characters used for their reserved purposes may be used unencoded within a URL.

So if you are trying to put **a URL** into **the URL**, you will either have to put up with the encoded characters because the colon `:` is not an allowed character except as the protocol seperator, and because a double slash `//` is not allowed except at the root of the URL, or you have to drop the protocol and the root from your URL and start with the domain. That is:

You can either do this:

```
/program/crid%3A%2F%2Fblah.com%2Fd1e5
```

or this

```
/program/blah.com/d1e5
```

A compromise when using Rails could be putting the protocol into a URL segment like so:

```
/program/crid/blah.com/d1e5
```

which you can collect in your `params` array with

```
match "program/:protocol/*program_id" => "program#details
```

The `*program_id` segment collects(globs) the rest of the url into a single entry in the `params` array.

you can recombine this in your controller if needed:

```
url = "#{params[:protocol]://#{params[:program_id]}}"
```

so that:

```
# GET /program/crid/blah.com/d1e5
params[:protocol]   #=> "crid"
params[:program_id] #=> "blah.com/d1e5"
url = "#{params[:protocol]://#{params[:program_id]}}"
#=> "crid://blah.com/d1e5"
```

Comment: Nice one! Thanks for the elaborate answer. I'll make use of this in the future. For now I'll stick to the "easy" approach using the URL-encoded parameter with `*program_id`.